# setting <select> color from <option> color

Tags: jquery

hi i would like to set text color of  tag from color of  tag

HTML

```
<select class="widocznosc">
    <option value="prywatna" class="note_0">prywatna</option>
    <option value="publiczna" class="note_2">publiczna</option>
    <option value="tylko dla grupy" class="note_16">tylko dla grupy</option>
</select>
```

CSS

```
.note_0
{
    color: #b59285;
}
.note_2
{
    color: #e7511e;
}
.note_16
{
    color: #6a89a5;
}
```

jQuery

```
jQuery("select.widocznosc").change(function(){
        jQuery(this).css("color", jQuery(this).children("option:selected").css("color")); 
    });
```

this works when i'm changing options, but i want set color when page loads before any changings

do help me pls

Comment: this will automatically occur as your css is loaded with the page and u have assigned class to each option. no need of jQuery on,  at all see here :http://jsfiddle.net/22H8p/   . automatically works on change

Comment: What element needs a set colour as the page loads? All of the options or just one of them?

Comment: @diEcho it works only in IE not in other browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
jQuery("select.widocznosc").change(function(){
        jQuery(this).css("color", jQuery(this).children("option:selected").css("color")); 
    }).change();
```

Note the added `.change()` at the end. This means that first you set a `change` handler on the dropdown, then you immediately call it.

**Note:** This will trigger every event handler you have associated with these dropdowns.

And I almost forgot [The Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zfxdX/1/).

**UPDATE:** Please note that you could rewrite your code like this to avoid unnecessary `jQuery()` calls (small performance gains, but it is considered a best practice also for cleaner code):

```
jQuery("select.widocznosc").change(function(){
    var $this=jQuery(this);
    $this.css("color", $this.children("option:selected").css("color")); 
}).change();
```

You save the result of `jQuery(this)` into a local variable and you use that instead of calling the function several time. You can use any variable name, I just used `$this` to indicate that it stores a jQuery collection (that's why the `$`).

Comment: it works but in firefox it sets white color, it sets whit color befeor your changes, any one know why ?

Comment: No, you will call _all_ 'change' events associated with specific select.

Comment: @gidzior I think it deserves its own question to get the best possible answers.

Comment: @Tadeck Yes, it will trigger every associated change handler. I will update my answer.

Comment: well, I believe that he should start learning to use document.ready function if he has to do anything similar latter on, he can add all functions needed to the ready part.

Comment: @Luci There is a good chance all his code is already in a `document.ready()` handler.

Comment: I am expecting an explanation from the downvoter. If you think my answer is not good enough, I would be happy to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

use this to change color at start up [ready() event](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the document ready event something like this.

Javascript

```
var selected_color;

jQuery("select.widocznosc").change(function(){ 
  jQuery(this).css("color", jQuery(this).children("option:selected").css("color")); 
});

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  selected_color = jQuery("select.widocznosc option:selected").css("color");
  jQuery("select.widocznosc").css("color", selected_color); 
});
```

Comment: it works but in firefox it sets white color, it sets whit color befeor your changes, any one know why ?

Comment: i agree with nick, yet you are repeating code, so every time he wants to change in something he has to do it on two places, it would be better to have it on a function, and call it.

Comment: The script executes after the whole page is ready. Do you have anything in your CSS that might be setting the color to white when the page loads?

Comment: -1 for unnecessarily repeated code and unnecessarily repeated selectors

Comment: @Luci Yeah the script isn't really optimised, but I wouldn't really worry about it if this is the only script on the page.

Comment: @bazmegakapa I answered it like this to show gidzior how to use document ready, which is a good thing to know if you're gonna be using jQuery.

Comment: @ Nick Pyett it is not necessary the only script.. did u check my way?

Comment: @Nick Pyett The fact that you wanted to demonstrate `document.ready()` does not mean you have to give sloppy code to the user. We should also promote best practices here.

Comment: Using document.ready is NOT sloppy, and neither is this code. The accepted answer will execute the same code on load and on change, which isn't ideal in all situations. Also, perfomance gains are out of the scope of this question, and should be addressed as a part of all the code in question.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
function modify_color(){
            $(".widocznosc").css("color", $(".widocznosc")).children("option:selected").css("color")); 
        } 


$(document).ready(function() { 

 modify_color();

}


$("select.widocznosc").change(modify_color);
```

Comment: Running the same selector three times could be easily avoided.