# setting color of <select> in firefox not working

Tags: html, css, firefox, google-chrome, internet-explorer-8

I'm actually having trouble perfectly reproducing this issue. However, I have a jsfiddle, and I can't get the select text to match the color of the selected option text.

http://jsfiddle.net/kralco626/9xJvF/8/

(similar to: [seting <select> color, FireFox 3.6.17 issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044633/seting-select-color-firefox-3-6-17-issue) and [setting <select> color from <option> color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044310/setting-select-color-from-option-color))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i edited your jsFiddle and adding !important worked in the css...

```
.approvedOption
    {color:green !important;
    }
    .pendingOption
    {color:blue !important;
    }
    .partialOption
    {color:blue !important;
    }
    .failedOption
    {color:red !important;
    }
```

i guess that you have some css which has more importance overwriting the color of this part above is a hacky fix but works for all intent and purpose!